# c++ next_permutation algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

let's say , a course with 8 participans, i must output the first 3 places in all possible ways.
ex :

123
124
125
126
127
128
213
so on..

I know there is `next_permutation` algorithm but it returns all the possible permuations with all the numbers (from 1 through 8), but i need first 3 places with all the participans
ex:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
1  2  3  4  5  6  8  7
```

Comment: Why there are two 127? And how about 111?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7d3xas6.aspx

Comment: What does 122 mean? That Person #1 came in first, and person #2 tied with himself for second?

Comment: possible duplicate of [n choose k implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095407/n-choose-k-implementation)

Comment: @Rob hah, there are bad answers, i proved you, in my comment on your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program produces the output you are looking for, not necessarily in the order you expect. If you want it in a particular order, you may need to capture the output and sort it. To see it run, [look here](http://ideone.com/60H3R).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Iterator>
inline bool next_combination(Iterator first,
  Iterator k,
  Iterator last);

int main () {
  int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
  do {
    do {
       std::cout << array[0] << array[1] << array[2] << "\n";
    } while(std::next_permutation(array, array+3));
  } while(next_combination(array,array+3,array+8));
}

template <typename Iterator>
inline bool next_combination(const Iterator first, Iterator k, const Iterator last)
{
   /* Credits: Thomas Draper */
   // http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097100/8747
   if ((first == last) || (first == k) || (last == k))
      return false;
   Iterator itr1 = first;
   Iterator itr2 = last;
   ++itr1;
   if (last == itr1)
      return false;
   itr1 = last;
   --itr1;
   itr1 = k;
   --itr2;
   while (first != itr1)
   {
      if (*--itr1 < *itr2)
      {
         Iterator j = k;
         while (!(*itr1 < *j)) ++j;
         std::iter_swap(itr1,j);
         ++itr1;
         ++j;
         itr2 = k;
         std::rotate(itr1,j,last);
         while (last != j)
         {
            ++j;
            ++itr2;
         }
         std::rotate(k,itr2,last);
         return true;
      }
   }
   std::rotate(first,k,last);
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The things you're after are not permutations, which is why `next_permutation` alone won't solve your problem.

First, you need to decide whether `123` is the same as `321` or not. If they are the same, you have plain [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). If they are different, you have [k-permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations#In_combinatorics) (different from plain permutations).

`std::next_permutation` gives you the next permutation, not the next k-permutation. There's no `std::next_combination`.

Fortunately, if you write your own `next_combination` (or find one on the internet), you can use it and `std::next_permutation` together to easily express the `next_k_permutation` algorithm.

With the correct terminology at hand it should be easy to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had misunderstood your question.

What you want is not `next_permutation`, it is what I would call next_combination.

So, I googled this term and… [link 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4675/Combinations-in-C) (codeproject), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095407/n-choose-k-implementation), [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436353/usage-of-this-next-combination-code), [link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211915/combination-and-permutation-in-c/2616837#2616837).

Comment: nah, it doesn't solve my problem, let me show you 

124
125
126
127
128
129
**134** //why is it starting at 134 instead of 132 than 134 and so on ?

Comment: @ddacot: so you want each permutation for each combination.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find all NC3 combinations, then permute them to find all possible ways of ranking them.

N Choose 3, can be done by generating [Banker's sequence](http://applied-math.org/subset.pdf) (my fav. ) There's a neat little way to generate all NC3 combinations with logN complexity each.

Once you start getting the combinations you can permute all the 6 permutations easily with your next_permutation() call.