# On-demand algorithm to return successive combinations of k elements from n

Tags: algorithm, combinations

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) shows how to write an algorithm to spit out, at one time, all combinations of **k** elements from **n**, avoiding permutations. But how would one write an algorithm that, *on demand*, gives the next combination (obviously, without precomputing and storing them)? It would be initialized with the ordered set of symbols **n** and an integer **k**, and would then be called to return the next combination.

Pseudocode or a good English narrative would be fine for my purposes - I'm not fluent in much beyond Perl and C and a bit of Java.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436353/usage-of-this-next-combination-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ORIGINAL WORDING**

(SKIP TO THE **UPDATE** BELOW)

---

1. Let's assume that the `n` elements are the integers `1..n`.
2. Represent every `k`-combination in increasing order (this representation gets rid of permutations inside the `k`-combination.)
3. Now consider the lexicographic order between k-combinations (of `n` elements). In other words, `{i_1..i_k} < {j_1..j_k}` if there exists an index `t` such that

   - `i_s = j_s` for all `s < t` and
   - `i_t < j_t`.
4. If `{i_1..i_k}` is a `k`-combination, define `next{i_1..i_k}` to be the next element w.r.t. the lexicographic order.

Here is how to compute `next{i_1..i_k}`:

- Find the largest index `r` such that `i_r + 1 < i_{r+1}`
- If no index satisfies this condition and `i_k < n`, set `r := k`
- If none of the above conditions can be satisfied, there is no next (and the `k`-combination equals `{n-k+1, n-k+2,... ,n}`)
- If `r` satisfies the first condition, set `next` to be `{i_1, ..., i_{r-1}, i_r + 1, i_{r+1}, ..., i_k}`
- If `r = k` (second condition), set `next := {i_1, ..., i_{k-1}, i_k + 1}.`

---

**UPDATE** (Many thanks to @rici for improving the solution)

1. Let's assume that the `n` elements are the integers `1..n`.
2. Represent every `k`-combination in increasing order (this representation gets rid of permutations inside the `k`-combination.)
3. Now consider the lexicographic order between k-combinations (of `n` elements). In other words, `{i_1..i_k} < {j_1..j_k}` if there exists an index `t` such that

   - `i_s = j_s` for all `s < t` and
   - `i_t < j_t`.
4. If `{i_1..i_k}` is a `k`-combination, define `next{i_1..i_k}` to be the next element w.r.t. the lexicographic order.
5. Note that with this order the smallest `k`-combination is `{1..k}` and the largest `{n-k+1, n-k+2,... ,n}`.

Here is how to compute `next{i_1..i_k}`

- Find the largest index `r` such that `i_r` can be incremented by `1`.
- Increment the value at index `r` and reset the following elements with consecutive values starting at `i_r + 2`.
- Repeat until no position can be incremented.

More precisely:

- If `i_k < n`, increment `i_k` by `1` (i.e., replace `i_k` with `i_k + 1`)
- If `i_k = n`, find the largest index `r` such that `i_r + 1 < i_{r+1}`. Then increment `i_r` by `1` and reset the following positions to `{i_r + 2, i_r + 3, ..., i_r + k + 1 - r}`
- Repeat until you reach `{n-k+1, n-k+2,... ,n}`

Note the *recursive* character of the algorithm: every time it increments the least significant position the tail is reset to the lexicographically smallest sequence that starts with the value just incremented.

---

Smalltalk code

```
SequenceableCollection >> #nextChoiceFrom: n
    | next k r ar |
    k := self size.
    (self at: 1) = (n - k + 1) ifTrue: [^nil].
    next := self shallowCopy.
    r := (self at: k) = n
      ifTrue: [(1 to: k-1) findLast: [:i | (self at: i) + 1 < (self at: i+1)]]
      ifFalse: [k].
    ar := self at: r.
    r to: k do: [:i | 
      ar := ar + 1.
      next at: i put: ar].
    ^next
```

Comment: You beat me to it, so I'll contribute a simplification. The first two bullets could be: "Find the largest r such that `i_r - r < n - k`." The fourth bullet should be "set next to `{i_1, ..., i_{r-1}, i_r + 1, i_r + 2, ..., i_r + k + 1 - r}`" and the fifth bullet is just a special case of the fourth one, so it could be reduced to three bullets.

Comment: @rici: I'm still trying to get my head around Leandro's solution, but I think it could work for *any* set of characters that have an ordering, despite his stated assumption that the `n` elements are integers. Your suggested simplification, I think, *requires* them to be the integers 1..n, since you perform arithmetic on the actual values (`i_r - r`). Am I correct about this? (EDIT: oops, never mind, I see that the solution does rely at least on the ability to increment an element)

Comment: Ah! I get it. The first two bullets are, in effect, looking for a potential "carry" and locating the leftmost element that would be affected by the right-to-left "ripple" of carries that would occur if `i_k` were incremented. Having located that element, it can increment the element to the immediate left, and then set the elements to the right to the progressively higher values demanded by point #2 ("Represent every k-combination in increasing order..."). So I do think @rici's simplification makes sense.

Comment: @Chap: Yes, technically his formulation only requires that you be able to compare two elements and find the successor of an element. And it could be modified to only require the successor operation. But in practice, you'd perform it on a vector of indexes, mirroring the modifications on a vector of symbols. It's

Comment: @chap: You can think of it this way: Imagine a rod with n notches and k beads. The beads have to rest in the notches. You start with all the beads as far to the left as possible. At each turn, you find the rightmost bead which can move right -- usually it's the rightmost bead --, and you move it one notch to the right and all the beads to the right of it (if any) as far left as possible. Continue until all the beads are as far to the right as possible.

Comment: @rici: Nice visual - that helps to clarify the indexing arithmetic. And you're quite correct - there's no limitation to using a sequence of integers, since they could then be used to index into any vector of `n` symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a prose description of how to do this. Start with your favorite iterative algorithm for generating all combinations. Then turn each loop variable into a state variable, and package it all into a class. Construct an instance of the class with **k** and **n** and initialize each state variable according to the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement most of these algorithms as you've described by converting them to an [Iterator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern).  This requires you to save the state of the algorithm between successive `nextELement()` calls.

If your language has support for coroutines, you may be able to convert the code more easily.  Python and C# both have a `yield` keyword that can be used to transfer control back to the calling function while retaining the state of algorithm you're executing.