# How to generate combination of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [combination and permutation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211915/combination-and-permutation-in-c)

I have a vector of say size "n". Lets say for example a vector of n=4, `<1,2,3,4>`. How can I generate all n-1 combinations of this vector. In this example, `4 chose 3`. I want the output to be `<1,2,3> <1,2,4> <1,3,4> <2,3,4>`. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [combination and permutation in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211915/combination-and-permutation-in-c), especially Charles Bailey's awesome solution.

Comment: There are as many `n-1` combinations of elements as `n`-combinations. Only the remaining element is not present. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've voted to close as well.

Answer (score 2):

Start by looking up STL's [next_permutation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/next_permutation.html) function.