# Traversing a vector in pairs, triplets,

Tags: c++, boost, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [combination and permutation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211915/combination-and-permutation-in-c)

Let's say I have a vector with the following elements: {1,2,3}. How can I traverse the vector in a pair-wise fashion. So the first iteration would be {1,2}, the second {1,3} and finally the third is {2, 3}.

For triplets there would be only one iteration: {1,2,3} in this case.

Are there algorithms in STL or boost to accomplish that?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: stacked for loops have traditionally accomplished this task. for(int x=0; x<vecSize; x++) for(int y=x+1; y<vecSize; y++) ...

Comment: Check this [SO Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211915/combination-and-permutation-in-c). This is actually a problem of combinations

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; ++i)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); ++j)
        std::cout << '{' << vec[i] << ',' << vec[j] << '}';
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the way I'm doing it. But I'm looking for a way in STL or Boost. If there isn't that's no biggie. But I was hoping for something like next_permutation, or so.