# Generating k permutations from n in C

Tags: c, permutation, python-itertools, heaps-algorithm

I basically need the equivalent result of the following Python `itertools` command in C:

`a = itertools.permutations(range(4),2))`

Currently my process involves first "choosing" 5 elements from 10 then generating permutations for those 5 elements as shown [here](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/djimenez/ut/utsa/cs3343/lecture25.html)

The issue with this approach is the order of the outputs. I need it to be (a), while what i get is (b), shown below.

```
a = itertools.permutations(range(4),2)
for i in a:
    print(i)

(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(1, 0)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 3)
(3, 0)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)

b = itertools.combinations(range(4),2) 
for i in b:
    c = itertools.permutations(i)
    for j in c:
        print(j)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(0, 2)
(2, 0)
(0, 3)
(3, 0)
(1, 2)
(2, 1)
(1, 3)
(3, 1)
(2, 3)
(3, 2)
```

An alternate approach which I am using is as follows

```
void perm(int n, int k)
{
    bool valid = true;
    int h = 0, i = 0, j = 0, limit = 1;
    int id = 0;
    int perm[10] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
        limit *= n;
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        id = i;
        valid = true;
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            perms[j] = id % n;
            id /= n;
            for (h = j - 1; h >= 0; h--)
                if (perms[j] == perms[h])
                {
                    valid = false; break;
                }
            if (!valid) break;
        }
        if (valid)
        {
            for (h = k - 1; h > 0; h--)
                printf("%d,", perms[h]);
            printf("%d\n", perms[h]);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Memory is my constraint, so I cannot store the permutations indefinitely. Performance needs to be better than the algorithm above, as when `n` is 50 and `k` is 10, I end up iterating through more invalid combinations(60+%)

I am aware of [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) for generating permutations in place but again it generates for entire array not k of n like I need.

Questions.

1. Is there a better way to do this than iterate n^k times?
2. Can I make a lazy iterator which moves to next permutation given current permutation?

**EDIT** this is not a duplicate of std::next_permutation implementation as that will permute and entire range of the input.
I have clearly mentioned i need k of n permutation .ie if my range is 10 I want all permutations of a length (k) say 5,  std::next_permutation works when length or permutation is same as length of input range

**UPDATE**
Here is an ugly recursive NextPerm solution which is about 4 times faster than my older solution and gives the incremental nextPerm like a Python lazy iterator.

```
int nextPerm(int perm[], int k, int n)
{
    bool invalid = true;
    int subject,i;
    if (k == 1)
    {
        if (perm[0] == n - 1)
            return 0;
        else { perm[0]=perm[0]+1; return 1; }
    }
    subject = perm[k - 1]+1;
    
    while (invalid)
    {
        if (subject == n)
        {
            subject = 0;
            if (!nextPerm(perm, k - 1, n))
                return 0;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < k-1; i++)
        {
            if (perm[i] != subject)
                invalid = false;
            else
            {
                invalid = true;subject++; break; 
            }
        }
    }
    perm[k - 1] = subject;
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    int a, k =3 ,n = 10;
    int perm2[3] = { 0,1,2}; //starting permutation
    unsigned long long count = 0;
    int depth = 0;
    do
    {
        for (a = 0; a < k - 1; a++)
            printf("%d,", perm2[a]);
        printf("%d\n", perm2[k - 1]);
        count++;
    }
    while (nextPerm(perm2,k,n));
    printf("\n%llu", count);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @anatolyg  I need select k of n permutations, that link just permutes a complete range

Comment: Along with using the code for `std::next_permutation`, [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28712605/9898745) is what you are looking for. The algorithm is an answer to the question : [Generating N choose K Permutations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28711797/9898745). The key is to reverse the elements from `k+1` to `n` after each permutation to avoid duplicate permutations.

Comment: @Emil no that works on the principle of choose k then permute those k, the order of permutations is different from my desired output. Look at behaviour difference in output of choose k and permute and my desired output. also specifically needs to be in C

Comment: I see what you are saying. This actually reminds me of heap's algorithm.

Comment: @Emil yup, have linked that in my question as well

Comment: @Emil based on Heaps algorithm I found a solution that works take a look

Comment: That has nothing whatsoever to do with Heap's algorithm. But if it works for you, that's cool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are simple modification to the standard permutation algorithms which will produce k-permutations.

#### Lexicographically-ordered permutations (aka `std::next_permutation`)

In C++, k-permutations can be generated by the simple expedient using `std::next_permutation`, and just reversing the `n-k`-suffix of the permutation before each call to `std::next_permutation`.

It's reasonably clear how that works: the algorithm generates permutations in order, so the first permutation starting with a given prefix has the remaining suffix in increasing order, and the last permutation with the same prefix has its suffix in decreasing order. Decreasing order is simply the reverse of increasing order, so a single call to `std::reverse` is sufficient.

The lexicographical order next-permutation algorithm is very simple:

1. Search backwards from the end for an element which could be increased by swapping it with some later element.
2. Once the rightmost such element is found, find the smallest following element with which it could be swapped, and swap them.
3. Sort the new suffix into increasing order (by reversing it, since it was previously in decreasing order).

An advantage of the lexicographical algorithm is that it transparently handles arrays with repeated elements. As long as the number of repetitions of any given element is O(1), `next-permutation` is amortized O(1) (per call), and in the worst case it is O(n). When generating k-permutations, the extra flip causes the cost of `next_k_permutation` to be O(n-k), which is effectively O(n) if `k` is fixed. That's still reasonably fast, but not as fast as non-iterative algorithms which can maintain state instead of doing the search in step 1 to figure out which element to move.

The following C implementation is equivalent to `std::reverse(); std::next_permutation();` (except that it swaps before reversing):

```
#include <stddef.h>

/* Helper functions */
static void swap(int* elements, size_t a, size_t b) {
  int tmp = elements[a]; elements[a] = elements[b]; elements[b] = tmp;
}
static void flip(int* elements, size_t lo, size_t hi) {
  for (; lo + 1 < hi; ++lo, --hi) swap(elements, lo, hi - 1);
}

/* Given an array of n elements, finds the next permutation in
 * lexicographical order with a different k-prefix; in effect, it 
 * generates all k-permutations of the array.
 * It is required that the suffix be sorted in ascending order. This
 * invariant will be maintained by the function.
 * Before the first call, the array must be sorted in ascending order.
 * Returns true unless the input is the last k-permutation.
 */ 
int next_k_permutation(int* elements, size_t n, size_t k) {
  // Find the rightmost element which is strictly less than some element to its
  // right.
  int tailmax = elements[n - 1];
  size_t tail = k;
  while (tail && elements[tail - 1] >= tailmax)
    tailmax = elements[--tail];
  // If no pivot was found, the given permutation is the last one.
  if (tail) {
    size_t swap_in;
    int pivot = elements[tail - 1];
    // Find the smallest element strictly greater than the pivot, either
    // by searching forward from the pivot or backwards from the end.
    if (pivot >= elements[n - 1]) {
      for (swap_in = tail; swap_in + 1 < k && elements[swap_in + 1] > pivot; ++swap_in) {}
    } else {
      for (swap_in = n - 1; swap_in > k && elements[swap_in - 1] > pivot; --swap_in) {}
    }
    // Swap the pivots
    elements[tail - 1] = elements[swap_in];
    elements[swap_in] = pivot;
    // Flip the tail. 
    flip(elements, k, n);
    flip(elements, tail, n);
  }
  return tail;
}
```

Here's a simple driver and a sample run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int intcmp(const void* a, const void* b) {
  return *(int*)a < *(int*)b ? -1 : 
         *(int*)a > *(int*)b ?  1 :
                                0 ;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  size_t k = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;
  if (argc < k + 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s K element...\n"
                    "       where K <= number of elements\n",
                    argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  size_t n = argc - 2;
  int elements[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) elements[i] = atoi(argv[i + 2]);
  qsort(elements, n, sizeof *elements, intcmp);
  do {
    const char* delimiter = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
      printf("%s%2d ", delimiter, elements[i]);
      delimiter = " ";
    }
    putchar('\n');
  } while (next_k_permutation(elements, n, k));
  return 0;
}
```

Sample run (with repeated element):

```
$ ./k_next_permutation 2 7 3 4 4 5
 3   4 
 3   5 
 3   7 
 4   3 
 4   4 
 4   5 
 4   7 
 5   3 
 5   4 
 5   7 
 7   3 
 7   4 
 7   5
```

#### Modified Heap's algorithm

As an example of an algorithm which maintains state, Heap's algorithm can be easily modified to produce k-permutations. The only change is that when the algorithm recurses down to position `n - k`, the k-suffix is reported as the k-permutation and the (n-k)-prefix is transformed the way the Heap algorithm would transform it if it were run to conclusion: the prefix reversed if its length is odd and rotated one to the left if its length is even. (That's a big hint about how Heap's algorithm works, by the way.)

Using the recursive algorithm is a bit annoying because it doesn't really allow incremental permutations. However, it's simple to follow. Here, I've just passed a functor into the recursive procedure which is called with each permutation in turn.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>

/* Helper functions */
static void swap(int* elements, size_t a, size_t b) {
  int tmp = elements[a]; elements[a] = elements[b]; elements[b] = tmp;
}
static void flip(int* elements, size_t lo, size_t hi) {
  for (; lo + 1 < hi; ++lo, --hi) swap(elements, lo, hi - 1);
}
static void rotate_left(int* elements, size_t lo, size_t hi) {
  if (hi > lo) {
    int tmp = elements[lo];
    for (size_t i = lo + 1; i < hi; ++i) elements[i - 1] = elements[i];
    elements[hi - 1] = tmp;
  }
}

/* Recursive function; the main function will fill in the extra parameters */
/* Requires hi >= lo and hi >= k. Array must have size (at least) lo + k */    
static bool helper(int* array, size_t lo, size_t k, size_t hi,
                       bool(*process)(void*, int*, size_t), void* baton) {
  if (hi == lo) {
    if (!process(baton, array + lo, k)) return false;
    if (lo % 2)
      flip(array, 0, lo);
    else
      rotate_left(array, 0, lo);
  }
  else {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < hi - 1; ++i) {
      if (!helper(array, lo, k, hi - 1, process, baton))
        return false;
      swap(array, hi % 2 ? 0 : i, hi - 1);
    }
    if (!helper(array, lo, k, hi - 1, process, baton))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

/* Generate all k-permutations of the given array of size n.
 * The process function is called with each permutation; if it returns false,
 * generation of permutations is terminated.
 */ 
bool k_heap_permute(int* array, size_t n, size_t k,
                    bool(*process)(void*, int*, size_t), void* baton) {
  assert(k <= n);
  return helper(array, n - k, k, n, process, baton);
}
```

Here's an example of its use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool print_array(void* vf, int* elements, size_t n) {
  FILE* f = vf;
  const char* delim = "";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    fprintf(f, "%s%2d", delim, elements[i]);
    delim = " ";
  }
  putc('\n', f);
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  size_t k = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;
  if (argc < k + 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s K element...\n"
                    "       where K <= number of elements\n",
                    argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  size_t n = argc - 2;
  int elements[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    elements[i] = atoi(argv[i + 2]);
  k_heap_permute(elements, n, k, print_array, stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./permut 2      1 5 9 7 3
 7  3
 9  3
 5  3
 1  3
 1  5
 7  5
 9  5
 3  5
 3  9
 1  9
 7  9
 5  9
 5  7
 3  7
 1  7
 9  7
 9  1
 5  1
 3  1
 7  1
```

Comment: but I am looking for incremental permutation? since these permutation act an indices for a large k dimensional data set (k>=10) and I need to beable to access nextPerm and possibly prevoiusPerm

Comment: Did you read my answer? My algorithm is exactly what you describe in the first part of your answer. I just didn't define swap and reverse methods and instead did those directly in place. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @joseph: Yes, they're essentially the same, now that I look at it. Maybe I should have left the Heap's k-permutation solution at the beginning.

Comment: Confirms that I'm not crazy :) anywho, I really like your explanation and implementation

Comment: @rici I'm removing my answer as yours is a million times better in every regard. Leaving mine would only take away.

Comment: I would love to.. only i mentioned 2 things.. code needs to be in c only, and it fails to compile as a C file i need to change my environment to cpp. 2nd there is an error in your second algorithm.

Comment: @JosephWood Heap permute does not give output in lexicographical order and first algorithm is worse that n^k iterations

Comment: @siddharth: the code is certainly C. Neither algorithm is n^k; what evidence do you have of that? And what error do you claim there is anything in the Heap algorithm? (It is certainly true that it does not produce lexicographic order. That's by design.)

Comment: Of course, there are n!/(n-k)! k-permutations of a set of n elements, so any algorithm which generates all of them will take O(n!/(n-k)!) to produce them all. There's no way around that.

Comment: @rici I am using a VC 2018 c environment and it fails to compile with a simple copy paste give 4000+ errors. that is besides the point, it could be a VC issue. 2nd the "minor" error is in th e k_heap function `return helper(array, n - k, k, n, baton, process);` baton and process args need to be reversed. 3rd you are only counting the recursion is the program order, not the flip,reverse and swap statements. run your programs for k = 5 and n = 52. you will get some interesting results. Your effective order is O(k!)(n!)/(n-k)!

Comment: @siddharth: Maybe you copy+pasted incorrectly. The only MSVC incompatibility I know of is the use of a VLA in the main function, which is hardly relevant to the algorithm implementation. I don't have MSVC but I checked it with gcc.godbolt.org: https://godbolt.org/g/u5kwnH (I changed `int elements[n]` to `int elements[52]` in that version to avoid the lack of VLAs.)

Comment: I fixed the copy&paste error I made with the change to argument order. Sorry about that, and thanks for reporting it.

Comment: I ran k_heap_permute with k=5 and n=52, as suggested, and it printed the expected 311875200 5-permutations in 144 seconds. Of course, most of that time is printing; when I changed the callback to just count calls and added counters to the helper functions, it took 6.2 seconds and reported "311875200 permutations; 7485004799 swaps; 311875200 flips; 0 rotate_lefts". (Since it always makes the same decision at the bottom of the recursion, you either get all flips or all rotate_lefts). The 7485004799 swaps are because flip calls swap 23 times (to flip 47 elements), plus one swap per permutation.

Comment: Interestingly, k_heap_permute with k=5 and n=53 took about half the time despite generating about 10% more permutations, because rotate_left is faster than flip. But both are O(n-k), so I think the time to produce all n!/(n-k)! permutations is (n-k)n!/(n-k)! == n!/(n-k-1)!. Why do you think it is multiplied by k! ?

Comment: @SiddharthChabra: So I figured out how to get rid of the (n-k) multiplier in the Heap's algorithm implementation, but I suppose you're not interested because of the interface and the fact that it generates the permutations in a different order. But just to let you know, I generated the 5/52 permutations in exactly 1 second in a single thread on an i7 laptop. That's 3 nanoseconds each, although of course all I do is count them.

Comment: @rici I am always interested in improvement. If you run my last implementation of next per. I get it to run n=52 k=5 in 1.5 seconds on a 6 year old i5. If you make nested for loops you get the perms in an insane 0.5 seconds. The problem with your implementation of heaps algorithm is that you are permuting elements in place . That means your algo is slowed down because you have to access elements which is an array lookup which is slower that an increment nor decrement. My implementation skips this. I am purmuting indices. So a swap for you in an increment for me. Hence my in order algo faster

Comment: @siddharth: That's an interesting point. Certainly, a general-purpose algorithm is going to be a bit slower. But I can still beat your generator using an in-place heap permuter, particularly as k grows larger (because of the k² factor from the backwards search).

Comment: @rici agreed but i need ordered perms which your faster algo doe now give