# Algorithm to get Cartesian product

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, cartesian-product

I have an array like `[0,2,3,0,1]` as input , and I need to find Cartesian product of `{0}x{0,1,2}x{0,1,2,3}x{0}x{0,1}`, more precisely I need to have output as following.

---

Input:

```
[0, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 3, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 3, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

I need a general algorithm. Any idea ? I would like to write it in c++.
Thanks

Comment: So you want to count up from 0 to the input value for each position?

Comment: any reason why `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]` is not in the list of output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [combination and permutation in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211915/combination-and-permutation-in-c)

Comment: From what I can tell this question isn't really about permutations, and is in fact much simpler.  What algorithm did you use to come up with your expected output based on the input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: If I am not wrong, the number of combinations should be `num_of_different_symbols^num_of_inputs`. In your case, you have 2 equal symbols (namely `0`), so you would discard one of them. So, you would have something like `4^5 = 1024` possible combinations, where 5 refers of course to the size of your array.

Comment: is that exactly the output you want for that input? Or its part of the output set.

Comment: There's a quite simple manual algorithm to do what you want. Think of the possible outputs when you have 2 inputs and the possible symbols are just 2, yes, I am talking about binary. If you have input `A` and `B`, the possible combinations are `A = 1` and `B = 1`, `A = 1` and `B = 0`, `A = 0` and `B = 0` and `A = 0` and `B = 1`. Write this down on a paper! Do you see any pattern?

Comment: It is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) that you want, not permutation nor combination.

Comment: The things you list are not permutations. A permutation is the same items arranged in a different order.

Comment: The sets for cartesian product are `{0} x {0,1,2} x {0,1,2,3} x {0} x {0,1}`

Comment: @WorldSEnder since 4th position in the input is 0 .

Comment: @TedHopp yes , for each non zero position

Comment: @user3914860, how are you going from the input [0,2,3,0,1] to `{0}x{0,1,2}x{0,1,2,3}x{0}x{0,1}`? I don't see the logical step there in order to draft an algorithm for a general input

Comment: @WorldSEnder I corrected it , someone added it to my question

Comment: @WorldSEnder: The numbers in the array are the last number of each set.

Comment: @user3914860: It is me who edited your question, and I repeat, it is not [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).Permutation of `[0,2,3,0,1]` will produce these number with all possible arrangements (so `{0,0,1,2,3}`, `{0,0,1,3, 2}`, .. `{3,2,0,0,1}`, `{3,2,1,0,0}`).

Comment: @Jarod42 you`re right , it is not permutation. But the problem is that , I need a general algorithm, it would be a part of my code and through my code,  the input array will be produced and then I need that type of output I mentioned, In each input I don`t know how many nonzero elements I would have, and in which position

Comment: @user3914860: I provide (as others) answer to your question, but you got lot of noise (in comment/answer) with misleading title/descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hard code solution would be:

```
for (int a1 : {0}) {
  for (int a2 : {0,1,2}) {
    for (int a3 : {0,1,2,3}) {
      for (int a4 : {0}) {
        for (int a5 : {0,1}) {
            do_job(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may use the following for a generic way (putting all `a`s into vector):

```
bool increase(const std::vector<std::size_t>& v, std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = it.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = size - 1 - i;
        ++it[index];
        if (it[index] > v[index]) {
            it[index] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void iterate(const std::vector<std::size_t>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> it(v.size(), 0);

    do {
        do_job(it);
    } while (increase(v, it));
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/RYi2JK)

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it seem like you want to count with mixed radix, and your input is the maximum digit value for each position.

A simple way is to use **arithmetic coding**, treating the max digit 0 positions specially. Here's pseudo-code for the case with no 0 max digits:

```
input radixes
let n_numbers = product_of radixes
for i = 0 to n_numbers-1 inclusive
    let n = i
    for digit_pos = 0 to number-of-radixes-1
        output n mod radix[digit_pos]
        let n = n div radix[digit_pos]
    output newline
```

I leave the treatment of 0 as max digit in a position, as an exercise. :)

---

I can't recall any particularly relevant support for this in the C++ standard library. I.e. it's mostly a language-independent question that has nothing to do with C++, nothing to do with permutations, and nothing to do with arrays. Provided my interpretation of it is correct: it would have been better it the problem was described also with words, not just an example.

Comment: There are no special cases for `0` as max digit :-)

Answer (score 0):

Recursion seems like the simplest way to approach this problem, given that you may not know the length of the input vector.  Something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cartesian {

  public static void printCartesian(String head, ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    if (array.size() == 0) {
      System.out.println(head);
      return;
    }
    if (array.size() == 1) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= array.get(0); ++i) {
        System.out.println(head + i + "]");
      }
      return;
    }
    // assert array.size() > 1
    int a0 = array.get(0);
    ArrayList<Integer> array0 = new ArrayList<Integer>(array);
    array0.remove(0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= a0; ++i) {
      printCartesian(head + i + ", ", array0);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] input = { 0, 2, 3, 0, 1 };
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(input));
    printCartesian("[", array);
  }
}
```

The initial call would be `printCartesian("[", a)` where `a` is an ArrayList containing the elements of your array in order. An extra `if` clause has to be added for `size == 1` because otherwise one too many commas is printed.

Translating this to C++ data structures shouldn't be difficult.