# Lambda/function of arbitrary arity and with captures as a function argument

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-functions

In my C++ programme, I often need to build a vector of values of a function on all the possible values of its arguments over some small finite field. For example, something like this:

```
int q = 7;
vector<int> GFq;
for (int x = 0; x < q; x++) GFq.push_back(x);

auto P = [q](int x, int y) -> int { return (x*x+y) % q; };
auto Q = [q](int x, int y) -> int { return (x+2*y) % q; };
auto f = [q,P,Q](int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
        -> int {return (P(x1,y1) + Q(x2,y2)) % q; }

vector<int> table;
for (int x1: GFq) for (int y1: GFq) for (int x2: GFq) for (int y2: GFq)
    table.push_back(f(x1,y1,x2,y2));
```

This pattern is so often repeated in my code that I naturally want to make it a function. So I need something like this:

```
template<typename F>  // not sure if I need to use templates
vector<int> tabulate(int q, F f) {
    // run through values 0..q-1 for all arguments of f
    // and store the values of f to the resulting vector
}
```

Some questions/issues:

- I want to be able to pass an arbitrary function to `tabulate()` including those of different arity (i.e. `f(x)`, `f(x,y)`, etc.)
- I want to construct the function I pass "on the fly", including usage of other functions (the same way as `f` is constructed from `P` and `Q` in the first code snippet
- if I manage to pass such a function, how can I run a loop over all possible arguments of `f` (i.e. `0..q-1` for each of its arguments) inside `tabulate()`?

Comment: kind of yes, but I also want to be able to call tabulate with `f` of two, three, etc. arguments

Comment: That is why you have the first template overload `tabulate(
 const Function f, Args&&... args)` in the given example code, where you pass `f` and forward all the arguments which should be called using `f` as second template parameter.

Comment: Hmm but when I try to call `std::vector<int> table = tabulate(
  GFq.begin(), GFq.end(),
  [q, P](int x1, int y1, int x2) { return (P(x1, y1) + x2) % q; }
 );` it gives me a compile error

Comment: Related to [algorithm-to-get-cartesian-product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713408/algorithm-to-get-cartesian-product/31713516#31713516)

Comment: @Jarod42 well, yes, but the main problem was not about iterating but passing a function of arbitrary arity

Comment: Depends of acceptable syntax and functor allowed for the call (`tabulate(f, ints(0,42), ints(20, 42), ints(10, 20))` with `ints` methods to create ranges or `tabulate<3>(f, ints(0,42)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to pass an arbitrary function to tabulate() including those of different arity (i.e. f(x), f(x,y), etc.)

Make `tabulate` a template that accepts objects of arbitrary types as functions.

> I want to construct the function I pass "on the fly", including usage of other functions (the same way as f is constructed from P and Q in the first code snippet

You can use a lambda directly as a function parameter.

> if I manage to pass such a function, how can I run a loop over all possible arguments of f (i.e. 0..q-1 for each of its arguments) inside tabulate()?

In pseudocode:

```
params = {0, ..., 0};

while (1)
{
    // Call function with `params` here.

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < params.size(); i++)
    {
        params[i]++;
        if (params[i] == q)
            params[i] = 0;
        else
            break;
    }
    if (i == params.size())
        break;
}
```

In practice you need to store parameters in a `std::array` (or `std::tuple`, as the code below does), and use `std::apply` to call your function with these parameters.

---

A complete implementation:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename ...P, std::size_t ...I>
bool increment_tuple_impl(T q, std::tuple<P...> &t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    auto lambda = [&](auto index) -> bool
    {
        auto &elem = std::get<index.value>(t);
        elem++;
        if (elem == q)
        {
            elem = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    };

    return (lambda(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}) || ...);
}

template <typename T, typename ...P>
bool increment_tuple(T q, std::tuple<P...> &t)
{
    return increment_tuple_impl(q, t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(P)>{});
}

template <typename T, typename F, std::size_t MaxArity, typename ...P>
auto tabulate_impl(T q, F &&f)
{
    if constexpr (!std::is_invocable_v<F, P...>)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(P) < MaxArity, "Invalid function.");
        return tabulate_impl<T, F, MaxArity, P..., T>(q, std::forward<F>(f));
    }
    else
    {
        using return_type = std::invoke_result_t<F, P...>;
        std::vector<return_type> vec;
        std::tuple<P...> params{};
        do
        {
            vec.push_back(std::apply(f, params));
        }
        while (increment_tuple(q, params));
        return vec;
    }
}

template <typename T, typename F>
auto tabulate(T q, F &&f)
{
    constexpr int max_arity = 8;
    return tabulate_impl<T, F, max_arity, T>(q, std::forward<F>(f));
}

int main()
{
    auto v = tabulate(3, [](int x, int y){return x*10 + y;});

    // Prints `0 10 20 1 11 21 2 12 22`.
    for (auto x : v)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
}
```

Comment: The solution works but I don't understand it, as it uses a lot of concepts I am not acquainted with :) I am now reading C++ documents to be able to understand how and why it works.