# How to generate all possible pairs from two vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, cartesian-product

I have two vectors:

```
vector<double>vec1={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
vector<double>vec2={6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

and I want to generate all possible pairs like:

```
{1,6}, {1,7}, {1,8}, {1,9}, {1, 10}, {2,6}, {2, 7}...
```

Comment: Two nested `for` loops?

Comment: Does order matter? 1,6 and 6,1  are equal or different?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211915/combination-and-permutation-in-c/5286517#5286517

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
        std::vector<int> b = {1,2,3,4,5};

        for(int i =0;i<a.size() ;i++)
             for(int j =0;j<a.size() ;j++)
                  std::cout << "{"<< a[i] << "," << b[j] << "} ";

}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You're printing the indices of the loop, not the values in the `vector`s.

Comment: @MikeBorkland my BAD , edited and fixed . But u could've edited it too

Comment: Poor values. OP had:
vector<double>vec1={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
vector<double>vec2={6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
which makes it more distinctive. 
"noone"'s example cannot tell the difference between 1,1 and 1,1 ...