# c++ array all possible combination

Tags: c++

My problem is that I have array of 14 digits I want to have a program that give all possible

combination within 8 digits that sum to **40**

for example

14 digits are `1,7,7,4,6,5,5,2,4,7,10,3,9,6,`

combination should like this

```
6+5+6+7+2+3+2+9=40

7+7+7+7+6+4+1+1=40
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205744/is-there-c-class-that-implements-operations-with-permutations

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: To generate a power set, use [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Answer (score 1):

Since the size of the array is just 14, so i won't work upon optimization.
Your problem can be solved by finding all **combinations using  `bitwise operations`**.

The idea is: Generate all the  subsets of a given array (set),  this set is known as a power set .For each of the subset(Combination), check whether the summations of the element(s) of the subset equals 40 or not.

Refer the following tutorials, to learn, ***how can you find all combinations using Bit Wise Operations***. http://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-bitwise-operations

The C++ implementation:

```
int main()
{
  int A[] = { 1, 7, 7, 4, 6, 5, 5, 2, 4, 7, 10, 3, 9, 6 };
  int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
  int desiredsum = 40;
  int total_soln=0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (1 << n); ++i)
  {
    vector < int >v;/*The vector contains element of a subset*/
    for (int j = 0; j <= n; ++j)
    {
            if (i & 1 << j)
                    v.push_back(A[j]);
    }
    if (v.size() == 8)/*Check whether the size of the current subset is 8 or not*/
    {       
            //if size is 8, check whether the sum of the elements of the current
        // subset equals to desired sum or not
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j)
            {
                    sum += v[j];
            }
            if (sum == desiredsum)
            {
                    for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j)
                    {
                            (j ==
                             v.size() - 1) ? cout << v[j] << "=" : cout << v[j] << "+";
                    }
                    total_soln++;
                    cout << desiredsum << " " << endl;
            }
    }
  }
  cout<<"Total Solutions: "<<total_soln<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

IDEONE LINK: http://ideone.com/31jh6c